# How to include delete and update functionality in a to-do list in node.js and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I would like to include this update and delete functionality on the same page.

I don't know how I can pass the particular item index that I want to delete from `list.ejs` to `app.js`.

**list.ejs:**

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <form action="/" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="inputfield" class="input-field">
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form action="/delete" method="POST">
      <% for (var i = 0; i < arrlist.length; i++) {%>
        <ul>
          <li><%= arrlist[i] %> <button type="submit" value="<%= i %>">Delete</button></li>
        </ul>
      <% } %>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```js
var list = []

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('list', { arrlist: list })
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var todo = req.body.inputfield
  list.push(todo)
  res.redirect('/')
})

app.post('/delete', function (req, res) {
  console.log(i)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Port working')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the button a `name`, for example `name="item"`.

Then you can read its `value` in your backend in `req.body[name]` (e.g. `req.body.item`), provided that you already have a body parser included in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to return list data, well order to do this you need to use promises and send aync request to server, here you just sending data to server only, but you need your client needs to hold for response axios or other libraries can help you to achieve this.

```js
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const todo = req.body.inputfield;
  list.push(todo);
  res.send(list);
});
```